# jQuery call custom function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How would I correctly call the specialHouse function after the h1 was clicked, in way that would still allow $(this) to represent div.content. Currently the below does not work with the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'specialHouse'"

```
function specialHouse()
{
    $(this).slideDown(500, function(){
      $(this).delay(2000).slideUp();
    });
 };

$('div.content').hide();
$('h1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('div.content').specialHouse();
})
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 6):

You have to tell jQuery about your new function:

```
jQuery.fn.specialHouse = function() {
   return this.slideDown(500, function(){
     $(this).delay(2000).slideUp();
   }
}
```

As we return `this` our function is chain able:

```
$("a").specialHouse().text("Hello World");
```

Comment: why do we have to return 'this' in order for the function to be chain-able :S

Comment: This is how every chain-able jQuery plugin works. `this` is returned and the next function may use it again.

Comment: FWIW, I think the other answer is better.  It works without modifying the OP's original function, and thus allows that function to continue to be used as a standalone event handler.

Answer (score 5):

The way you've tried it works only for jQuery plugins. You can however invoke the function like this (the context `this` will be set as expected):

```
$('h1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('div.content').each(specialHouse);
});
```

Comment: good way to do it without converting that function into a plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('div.content').hide();
$('h1').on('click', function(){
    specialHouse($(this).next('div.content'));
}) 

function specialHouse(elem){
  $(elem).slideDown(500, function(){
     $(this).delay(2000).slideUp();
   });
};
```

Comment: The OP specifically requested `$(this)` - not a parameter.